# arguments for breaking (bad) code conventions

Tags: oop

The current code base that i am working on is "legacy" ( not in the age but the way things are  a laid out ) , although codebase is fairly new it follows outdated conventions like creating an interface for every concrete (service)class, fat services and thin models, procedural blobs of code .

What are some arguments for breaking (bad) conventions?

Comment: The question title and the question in the body don't seem to ask the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the very same for which you promote new conventions.The conventions you mostly mention are about design, it should be quite easy to reason about pros of a good OO design versus procedural.